# Trouble redirecting sub.example.com to sub.example.com/directory/

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a website set up at example.com/directory/ currently. /directory/ is set up to display different contents depending on the subdomain, that part is working fine. I'm having trouble editing my httpd.conf file to work correctly though.

Obviously I can only set up my A records for sub.example.com to point to example.com and not example.com/directory/ so I've set up some rules in my httpd to get around this, but they don't seem to be working. This is what I've got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ /directory/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ /directory/$1 [NC,L]
```

What seems to be happening though is those rules just direct each subdomain to example.com/directory and drop the subdomain completely. I'm a little lost as to what I need to change here, I'm not very well versed in Apache.

I know this should be simple, but I can't seem to find any documentation that is straightforward enough for me to understand, does anybody have any pointers?

Comment: You use both `folder` and `directory` in your rewrite rules.   Shouldn't those be the same?

Comment: You also say that you want to "redirect", but your rules don't have the `[R=301]` flag in them that would tell rewrite to do the redirect rather than serving the content from one URL at another.

Comment: Why use mod_rewrite at all? Why not just create a virtual host for sub.example.com and make its `DocumentRoot` set to `/path/to/directory`